# Add user to Directory role in azure active directory via Microsoft graph SDK\API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've created an API project in dotNet to get some data from microsoft.graph using SDK.
I managed to get all the users and all groups and see the role of each user (like Billing administrator / Application administrator, etc.), but I can not find a way to update or change the role to a user or group through the SDK / API.
I guess right now this option is not supported through API / SDK. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a HTTP request to the directory role using role-id or role-templateid for adding the user:

```
POST /directoryRoles/{role-id}/members/$ref 
POST /directoryRoles/roleTemplateId={roleTemplateId}/members/$ref
```

**Example :**

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/fe8f10bf-c9c2-47eb-95cb-c26cc85f1830/members/$ref
or 
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/roleTemplateId=88d8e3e3-8f55-4a1e-953a-9b9898b8876b/members/$ref 
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/UserObjectID"
}
```

**You can use C# to add user to directory role :**

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var directoryObject = new DirectoryObject
{
    Id = "bb165b45-151c-4cf6-9911-cd7188912848"
};

await graphClient.DirectoryRoles["{directoryRole-id}"].Members.References
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(directoryObject);
```

**Reference :**

[Add user to directory role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Directory Role Id's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#role-template-ids)